# Print formation

Tags: java, formatting, println

I asked a question early and got some great help :D [My first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215597/calling-a-method-that-only-prints-out-a-loan-statement). I thought I was out of the woods but I guess not.  I am setting up/formation the information that my program is getting but I am running into a problem when trying to print my variable "time" if any one could point out what I am doing wrong I would be much obliged.

the section of code I believe to be the problem is:

```
// this class prints a loan statement showing the amount borrowed
    // and the amount borrowed, the annual interest rate, the number of months
    // and the monthly payment
    public static void loanStatement(double principle, double interest, int time, double mPayment)
    {
       System.out.printf("%2s%13s%8s%20s%n", "Principle", "Interest", "Time", "Monthly Payment");
       System.out.printf("%2.2f%10.2f%10.2f%n", +principle, +interest +time);
       System.out.println("monthly payment is" +mPayment);
       System.out.println("interest is" +interest);
       System.out.println("Time is" +time);
```

when I take out the +time and remove the 10.2f (I tried many different combinations) I get no errors. I also had it with the time and Monthly payment variables being printed and got a weird mesh of numbers.

I put in the other printlns because I wanted to check that the program was returning the proper values and it is.

below is the formatting errors I am getting

```
Principle     Interest    Time     Monthly Payment
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '10.2f'
15000.00     36.07  at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2487)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at loanpayment.LoanPayment.loanStatement(LoanPayment.java:89)
    at loanpayment.LoanPayment.main(LoanPayment.java:55)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

I hope what I am asking make sense to you guys, and thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are providing only two inputs here:

```
   System.out.printf("%2.2f%10.2f%10.2f%n", +principle, +interest +time);
```

whereas it requires three. Maybe you are missing to put the comma(`,`) before `+time` 
Try this if logical for you:

```
   System.out.printf("%2.2f%10.2f%10.2f%n", +principle, +interest, +time);
```

Comment: wooooooooooooooow, I feel so stupid now xD damn commas....this is what I get for rushing and getting annoyed. thank you! also I needed a d instead of f since time is an int. but thanks again!

Comment: I plan on doing that as soon as stack lets me, apparently you can not accept an answer so quickly  xD

Comment: @JeffreyQuinn no probs :-) just do it whenever u get a chance to.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma in your format...

```
System.out.printf("%2.2f%10.2f%10.2f%n", +principle, +interest +time);
                                                              ^--- Missing comma
```

Which is trying to add the last two values, try

```
System.out.printf("%2.2f%10.2f%10.2f%n", +principle, +interest, +time);
```

instead...